# Function for modify filename on a view from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I created a function to retrieve the original path of an image stored in database.

```
public function getImageWork($suffix)
{
    $basePath = 'uploads/works/';
    $fullname = pathinfo($this->images, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $imageWork = $basePath . $fullname . $suffix;

    if (file_exists($imageWork)) {
        return URL('/') . '/' . $imageWork;
    } else {
        return $imageWork = URL('/') . '/img/no-avatar.jpg';
    }
}
```

I create several different image sizes that I store in the same folder from the same name but at the end I add, for example, `_cover` or `_thumb` and thanks to this function, it allows me in my view to make `$ image->getImageStudents('_ thumb.jpg')`

Only, I'm in front of a different case and I can't make it work.
I have an image gallery, and in my DB, the images are stored under an array.

```
["uploads/img1.jpg","uploads/img2.jpg","uploads/img3.jpg"…]
```

How I can do to change my function so that in my foreach, it works.

Here I do `pathinfo($this-> images)` but by doing that, I recuperate the entire array, and I can not seem to work.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate both *single value* and *array* for images in `getImageWork` method, you need to refactor it in the following way,

```
public function getImageWork($suffix = ""){
    $basePath = 'uploads/works/';
    $imagePathArr = array();
    $images = is_array($this->images) ? $this->images : array($this->images); 
    foreach($images as $image){
        $fullname = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $imageWork = $basePath . $fullname . $suffix;

        if (file_exists($imageWork)) {
            $imagePathArr[] = URL('/') . '/' . $imageWork;
        } else {
            $imagePathArr[] = URL('/') . '/img/no-avatar.jpg';
        }
    }
    return $imagePathArr;
}
```

As an output, the above method will return an array of image paths which you can use later in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the code up in two functions, where one function takes in an image variable instead of relying on `this`.

Something like this:

```
public function getImageWork($suffix)
{
    if (!is_array($this->images)) {
        return $this->getSingleImageWork($this->images, $suffix);
    }

    $output = [];
    foreach ($this->images as $image) {
        $output[] = $this->getSingleImageWork($images, $suffix);
    }
    return $output;
}

public function getSingleImageWork($image, $suffix) {
    $basePath = 'uploads/works/';

    $fullname = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $imageWork = $basePath . $fullname . $suffix;

    if (file_exists($imageWork)) {
        return URL('/') . '/' . $imageWork;
    }

    return $imageWork = URL('/') . '/img/no-avatar.jpg';
}
```

Note: I am not sure how the variables are, but I assume here that `$this->images` is either a variable of some kind, or a array of values.